# Получение данных из network при открытии сайта в браузере JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

Необходимо при открытии сайта в браузере получать данные из вкладки network на JS
[image: инструменты хром]

Например необходимы следующие данные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу получить эти данные на JS при открытии ссылки?

Comment: Что-то мне кажется что такие манипуляции в приницпе недоступны. Если вы хотите проверить доступность конкретной функции, то для этого можно воспользоваться setInterval и if. Ну или примерно так.

Comment: Хочу проверять, авторизован ли я, при открытии сайта. Возможно такое?

Comment: Так для этого надо использовать метод API))

Comment: Это не совсем то

Answer (score 0):

#### Никак

Если вы хотите получить данные из Network значит вы хотите следить за данными в сети и частично за данными со стороны клиента. Такого браузер никогда не допустит. Решение этой задачи будет означать что вы нашли дыру в работе браузера.

---

Максимум, что можно сделать это получить информацию о выполнения http запросов.
Об этом [поговорили](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17021168/12903672) на англоязычной стороне